# css image link change opacity on hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

```
<div id="contentwrap">
<a id="contentimage" href=""></a>
    <p class="content">
        </p>
    </div>

 #contentimage {
    display:block;
    background:url(../images/contimg.jpg);
    top:500px;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
}
#contentimage:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

I'd like the opacity of the image link to change when I hover. However it's not even treating the image as a link (no click option)?

Comment: Works here.. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/QuC4u/

Comment: your fiddle is working fine and it is treating image as link..

Comment: yea forgot i had a lesser z-index on the parent div preventing me clicking the <a>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
<img id="contentimage" src="link to image">
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good except for one error.
In your css, use url with quotes
background:url(**'**../images/contimg.jpg**'**);

Edit: Your code works fine.

Comment: Yes, while quotes are proper syntax, virtually every browser will deal with the image correctly even if left unquoted.

Comment: You are correct. Then the code works fine. There is no problem.